# Is it the right way to integrate REST Web Service with Activemq in Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, activemq-classic

I'm creating a new spring boot application to handle REST requests and responses in between multiple applications. So, Is it the right way to make it by queuing the incoming requests using Activemq for load balancing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of topics.
 1. Communication between Applications. For this you can use REST or Activemq. But it depends on which type of communication you want. REST is synchronous and Activemq is asynchronous.
2. Regarding Load balancing, you can achieve this using many other tools(both software and hardware). If you want to use Activemq for the sole purpose of Load balancing, it is not a good idea.

REST is based on http and Activemq is based on JMS. They are two different things.

Comment: but what about mapping request to jms and unmapping response from the same jms object which is sent through activemq.

Comment: sorry. didnt understand. can you explain